# how to change drawer anchor value based on screen size

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer

how to change drawer position according to screen size in mui(matrial ui)
change the anchor value

we need to change the anchor value according to screen size
like in mobile drawer open right side and in laptop or computer open in left side

`<Drawer anchor={"left"} open={true} > My Drawer </Drawer>`

Comment: were you able to able to do so. I'm also going through this problem